# Where are the Manual Overrides?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In rescuing the recruits/students/biotics from Orion Hall I am asked to find the manual overrides. I have no idea where they are as I missed the first few words that potentially contained a clue as to where I am supposed to look and now the "Objective Indicator" says "Find Manual Overrides."

So, where are the manual overrides and how do I move on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The manual override controls are upstairs in Orion Hall by the students you aided in combat.** If you haven't done so yet, you first need to deactivate the Cerberus camera control. The camera control is on a bench near where the Atlas mech pushed through earlier.

**The best way to see what I'm referring to is to check the [IGN video walkthrough](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4I6ZwxdRro#t=22m03s) at about mark 22:03.** I've linked that specific section in the previous URL. If you need the camera override, just rewind a few seconds.

Door override:
[image]

Camera control (ignore this image if the camera control has already been accessed):
[image]

Comment: I swear, I wondered around in this room for 10 minutes looking for the overrides. The tricky thing is I walked by them once looking for the laptop but you can't interact with the table until you are told to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should be marked on your map. If not:

> Now, go upstairs and in the central room, get the Datapad, near the window, then the Assault Rifle Precision Scope near the monitors next to the panel you have to use to override the door. Go down and force the door below the central room.

Source: http://vgfaq.com/walkthroughs/mass-effect-3-grissom-academy-investigation-side-mission-walkthrough/